# how to upgrade infinispan 14.0.10 in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, bitnami, infinispan

I'm running keycloak v20.0.5 (deployed from the bitnami project) with infinispan 13.9 and I need to upgrade infinispan to v14.0.10. I've looked online and there are no resources online to show how I can do that? I've checked infinispan guide for bare-metal installation and it only shows how to add infinispan to the build pom.xml.
Has anyone here done something similar? or can refer me to a step-by-step procedure?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use Keycloak 21 which ships with Infinispan 14?

Comment: @pruivo it doesn’t come with v14.0.10. It was released with keycloak v22 but we can’t upgrade to it yet!

Comment: Yes KC 21 uses ISPN 14.0.9 but you can replace the JAR inside it. Anyway, ISPN 14 does not ensure API compatibility with ISPN 13. If you replace the JAR in KC 20, it may or may not work.